# What does the gnuwin32 program: [.exe do?

Tags: gnu, gnuwin32

Looking in the gnuwin32/bin directory, there is an odd-looking program file named `[.exe`

I couldn't find it in the documentation, gnuwin32.sourceforge.net or in a google search, so I ran it and got:

```
$ [
[: missing `]'
$
```

so I gave it ] as a parameter and got

```
$ [ ]

$
```

It didn't complain, so I assumed it was on the right track. I tried:

```
$ [ hello ]
```

again, no complaints. so I tried an arithmetic expression:

```
$ [ 1 + 1 ]
[: +: binary operator expected
$
```

I tried a bunch of different combinations, including prefix & postfix notation but nothing seemed to work. What does this thing do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used to evaluate *conditional* expressions.
It is equivalent to (possibly a symlink to?) the `test` executable.
The manpage is [here](http://www.ss64.com/bash/test.html).

You may see this in a lot of bash scripts:

```
if [ "$LOGNAME" = "scott" ]
then
    echo "Logged in as Scott"
else
     echo "incorrect user"
fi
```

The funny thing is, the **`[`** is not part of the bash language, it's actually an executable whose return code is used by the 'IF'. This is the reason why the space after the **`[`** and its first argument is mandatory - if it would be omitted, the script would try to execute **`["$LOGNAME"`** and fail.

You can't do arithmetical operations with it - use **`expr`** for that (see [here](http://www.ss64.com/bash/expr.html)).
However, you can test for a wide range of file properties (does it exist? what type is it? etc) as well as use comparison operators on strings and numbers.

Answer (score 6):

```
test a
```

==

```
[ a ]
```

It's just sugar

Edit: To clarify, that's the conditional syntax, e.g. [ "a" = "a" ]

Answer (score 0):

Another answer already mentioned it is the same as `test`. On bash, it is also a builtin, so you can get the help for it with the `help` builtin (`help test`).